# How can I use multi-environment configuration to set each root URL?

Tags: config, database, multi-environment

I'm building www.mynewcraftsite.com.au, but I also wanna create www.mynewcraftsite.dev which is a testing server to preview to my clients. I've heard that I can set this up with Craft without going through the drudgery of downloading/uploading databases and updating urls in the db, users ... etc.

I've been reading the Craft CMS documentation for "Multi-Environment Configs".  So far I've got this in my db.php file;

```
return array(
    //All environments
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'dashing-print',
        'password' => 'f#$njEwFRn3&2',
        'database' => 'dashing-print',
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft'
    ),

    //Testing environment
    'www.mynewcraftsite.dev' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'www.dashingprint.dev'
    ),

    //Live environment
    'www.mynewcraftsite.com.au' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'www.dashingprint.com.au'
    )
);
```

It works EXCEPT when I go to www.mynewcraftsite.dev and then click on the links, I end up back on www.mynewcraftsite.com.au (eg. Instead of going to www.mynewcraftsite.dev/services, I go to www.mynewcraftsite.com.au/services. In order to get to the correct page I gotta write up the whole url www.mynewcraftsite.dev/service into the google chrome url bar.)

The siteURL property isn't doing anything, there's gotta be something else that I gotta stick in there in order to rewrite the urls.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure to change the "Site URL" setting to `{siteUrl}` in your control panel settings...

> Control Panel > Settings > General > "Site URL"

Within your config file, you'll also want to put your `siteUrl` value inside of an [Environment-Specific Variables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables) sub-array:

```
'mynewcraftsite.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://www.mynewcraftsite.dev/'
    )
),
'mynewcraftsite.com.au' => array(
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://www.mynewcraftsite.com.au/'
    )
)
```

---

Here's how Craft is compiling all of that...

Within each of your environment configurations, there are many [config settings](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings) that you can apply to that specific environment. Additionally, each environment can have a sub-array called `environmentVariables`, which allows you to set whatever unique variables you want. The most common examples are `siteUrl` and `fileSystemPath` (great for setting up assets sources), but you can truly set whatever environment variables you want.

Once you've set the `siteUrl` value in your environment variables array, you now need to use that value... This is where the control panel settings page comes into play. Changing "Site URL" to simply `{siteUrl}` tells Craft to pull that value from your environment variables.

**IMPORTANT:** Notice the single set of curly braces, and the lack of spacing between the variable name and the braces. This is the syntax difference between **environment variables** and **Twig variables**.

That's it! When you create a path, Craft will use whatever is in the "Site URL" setting. And since that's pulling in your environment variable, that's what you'll get.

---

Lastly, allow me to point out a few things in your example which may also be stopping this from working for you (feel free to update the example in your question to fix these issues)...

**Most importantly:** You're combining data that should be stored in two separate files... `craft/config/db.php` and `craft/config/general.php`. While the multi-environment format is the same, you'll need to separate the data shown in your example. Put most of your settings into `general.php`, only the following belong in `db.php`:

- `server`
- `user`
- `password`
- `database`
- `tablePrefix`

You also have an errant line of code in your example... This line should definitely be removed:

```
'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.
```

Finally, you've left some crucial security information in your example... All of your database connection info is exposed (as well as your true domain names in your `siteUrl` examples).

---

Hope that helps... If you fix the bugs in your example code, I'll remove my corresponding notes from this answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The siteUrl value you are trying to set should not be set in the `db.php` file.  It needs to be set in the `general.php` file.  It also seems like you have a few other variables that should be moved over to `general.php` too.

You have one line that needs to be removed completely or commented out.  `'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.` is not correct.

**general.php**

```
return array(
    //All environments
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    )

    //Testing environment
    'www.mynewcraftsite.dev' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://www.mynewcraftsite.dev'
        )
    ),

    //Live environment
    'www.mynewcraftsite.com.au' => array(
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://www.mynewcraftsite.com.au'
        )
    )
);
```

**db.php**

```
return array(

    //All environments
    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft'
    ),

    //Testing environment
    'www.mynewcraftsite.dev' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'testuser',
        'password' => 'testpassword',
        'database' => 'testdatabase'
    ),

    //Live environment
    'www.mynewcraftsite.com.au' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'liveuser',
        'password' => 'livepassword',
        'database' => 'livedatabase'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this helpful: [Multi-Environment Config for Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/multi-environment-config-for-craft-cms)